# Crossbar : Non WAMP client as an authentication node

Tags: django, websocket, wamp, autobahn, crossbar

Question in high level: How to configure Crossbar to authenticate WAMP clients through a web server which has access to user DB.

Description:

With [crossbar dynamic authentication](http://crossbar.io/docs/Challenge-Response-Authentication/), a WAMP node (with access to user DB) can register an authentication function as follows.

```
def authenticate(realm, authid, details):
   ## return credentials (secret + role) for user 'authid'
   return {'secret': 'mypassword', 'role': 'sales'}

yield self.register(authenticate, 'com.example.authenticate')
```

Of course, crossbar will have dynamic authentication configured as well.

```
"auth": {
           "wampcra": {
                         "type": "dynamic",
                         "authenticator": "com.example.authenticate"
                      }
        }
```

In my case, user DB is with a Django HTTP REST server, which is not a regular WAMP client.

However, I see there is this [HTTP Callee](http://crossbar.io/docs/HTTP-Bridge-Services-Callee/) REST API provided by the crossbar HTTP Bridge Service. I see that you can configure crossbar to register a WAMP procedure (say com.myapp.rest) which sends requests to a HTTP server (say https://httpbin.org/) as follows.

```
"type": "class",
"classname": "crossbar.adapter.rest.RESTCallee",
"realm": "realm1",
"extra": {
            "procedure": "com.myapp.rest",
            "baseurl": "https://httpbin.org/"
         }
```

Looking at above, I'm thinking of providing the authentication functionality (as per my understanding) with my web server as follows.

1. When a regular WAMP client want to connect to the router, crossbar will issue RPC call to authenticate.
2. Then using the HTTP Callee service, crossbar will translate the WAMP procedure to HTTP requests, which will land at my web server.
3. In my web server, I will extract the authentication parameter, authenticate the user and return the success/failure response.

So it looks like, it could work.

However, I see there's special syntax for calling that procedure from a WAMP client.

```
@inlineCallbacks
def onJoin(self, details):
    res = yield self.call("com.myapp.rest",
                          method="GET",
                          url="",
                          params={
                                  .....
                              })
```

which is different to how you call a regular RPC

```
res = yield self.call(u'com.myapp.add2', 2, 3).
```

Question: Is it possible to follow my proposal (steps 1 to 3), for crossbar to ask for authentication info from my web server.

Comment: The question is whether I (or WAMP router) can call a RPC (provided with HTTP) without 'method' and 'url' parameters.

Comment: Why don't you have a WAMP component which is called with the regular authentication RPC by Crossbar, and then call the REST endpoint from that? It's one more step, but you'd get around the problem of the non-standard REST RPC call.

Comment: @gzost valid suggestion! Is it possible to run a WAMP client inside crossbar.io (externally of course)?

Comment: I think this is a nice to have feature for crossbar.io

Comment: "inside Crossbar.io" and "externally" seem to contradict each other ;) You can start WAMP components from a Crossbar.io config, see e.g. http://crossbar.io/docs/Guest-Configuration/